# How can I call a function in a NG-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a little problem, i wish to call a function within ng-repeat and not like this example, the fucntion remove duplicate value, but it doesn't work as i wish, i mean it remove duplicate from the string and not from the loop.

This is the HTML code, the "UNIQUE" function is to remove duplicate contents.

```
<tr ng-repeat="compet in discipline.compets">
    <td class="col-sm-2 feiCenterAlign"><label>{{unique(compet.eventCode)}}</label></td>   <td class="col-sm-2 feiCenterAlign"><div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2"><input type="number" ax-numeric-integer class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="compet.fhi.presented"></div></td>
    <td class="col-sm-2 feiCenterAlign"><div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2"><input type="number" ax-numeric-integer class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="compet.fhi.box"></div></td>
    <td class="col-sm-2 feiCenterAlign"><div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2"><input type="number" ax-numeric-integer class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="compet.fhi.notAccepted"></div></td>
    <td class="col-sm-2 feiCenterAlign"><div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2"><input type="number" ax-numeric-integer class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="compet.fhi.withdrawn"></div></td>
    <td class="col-sm-2 feiCenterAlign"><div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2"><input type="number" ax-numeric-integer class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="compet.fhi.accepted"></div></td>
</tr>
```

And this is the "UNIQUE" function code .

```
unique: function(array) { 
        var len = array.length; 
        var out = [];
        var obj = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            obj[array[i]] = 0;

        }
        for (var j in obj) { 
            out.push(j);
        }

        return out;
    },
```

thanks so much for your helps

PS : this is a link for a screenshot : hpics.li/d44d002 .
the RED cercle is the "compet.eventCode" .
the GREEN cercle is the value, and i want to display only once every duplicated value.

Comment: What duplicates do you want to remove exactly?

Comment: Maybe using [filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) might be a solution.

Comment: Can you post a sample of what `compet.eventCode` looks like?

Comment: question is not clear. Show a data sample and expected results

Comment: the duplicates to remove is "compet.eventCode", i don't want to show the same eventCode, if it exists more than once so i would show it once .

Comment: The "compet.eventCode" looks like : "CDIY","CDIJ","CDIP","CDIOJ","CDIOJ","CDIOP","CDIOY","CDIY","CDIJ","CDIP" but  separated

Comment: This is a screen shot of what i want and what i have.
The RED cercle is the "compet.eventCode" .
The GREEN cercle is what it s displayed, and i want to remove the duplicate content 

this is the link of the screen : http://hpics.li/d44d002

Answer (score 2):

Angular UI has a [filter for removing duplicates](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/#/unique):

```
<tr ng-repeat="compet in discipline.compets | unique:'field name'">
```

**Edit:** This is kind of reinventing the wheel, but since you can't add the Angular UI library to your project, you can manually add the `unique` filter (from original Angular UI source code):

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Filters out all duplicate items from an array by checking the specified key
 * @param [key] {string} the name of the attribute of each object to compare for uniqueness
 if the key is empty, the entire object will be compared
 if the key === false then no filtering will be performed
 * @return {array}
 */
angular.module('myApp', []).filter('unique', ['$parse',
    function ($parse) {

        return function (items, filterOn) {

            if (filterOn === false) {
                return items;
            }

            if ((filterOn || angular.isUndefined(filterOn)) && angular.isArray(items)) {
                var newItems = [],
                    get = angular.isString(filterOn) ? $parse(filterOn) : function (item) {
                        return item;
                    };

                var extractValueToCompare = function (item) {
                    return angular.isObject(item) ? get(item) : item;
                };

                angular.forEach(items, function (item) {
                    var isDuplicate = false;

                    for (var i = 0; i < newItems.length; i++) {
                        if (angular.equals(extractValueToCompare(newItems[i]), extractValueToCompare(item))) {
                            isDuplicate = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!isDuplicate) {
                        newItems.push(item);
                    }

                });
                items = newItems;
            }
            return items;
        };
    }
]);
```

Comment: I'm using AngularJS 1.0.8, and i don't think that the "UNIQUE" filter is available

Comment: It isn't. I said that it's part of the [Utils](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/) from from [Angular UI](http://angular-ui.github.io/) library.

Comment: Then I can't do it this way :/

Comment: Why don't you include this library?

Comment: Well, I don't understand why, but in this case you can create your own `unique` filter.

Comment: This is a screen shot of what i want and what i have. The RED cercle is the "compet.eventCode" . The GREEN cercle is what it s displayed, and i want to remove the duplicate content. this is the link of the screen : hpics.li/d44d002

Comment: I added it to my code, but i have this error "Error: Unknown provider: uniqueFilterProvider <- uniqueFilter"

Comment: This happens because the `$injector` can't find the `uniqueFilter` dependency, which may occur for many reasons. Read [this article](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr) from the AngularJS documentation. Also make sure you included the file in the `index.html` file.

Answer (score 0):

The ng-repeat directive will display what is in the model. Therefore you want to change the model. I forget where I came across this clever code (**IT IS NOT MINE**).

```
Array.prototype.unique = function () {
    return (this.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, index, array) {
    return (Array.isArray(previousValue) ? (previousValue.indexOf(currentValue) < 0 ? previousValue.concat(currentValue) : previousValue) : [ previousValue ]);
  }));
};
```

Here is [an example](http://plnkr.co/edit/WrqBO8UrY1AFRccBfrDm) that uses the above function and a button to display a unique model or not. If you only want to display a unique array it might be worth making the array unique when you receive it.

```
$http.get('/aurl').success(function (data, status) {
  $scope.data = data.unique();
});
```